# A Error about DLL encounterd importing python package (in tmux environment)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, dll, tmux

I encounter a problem about DLL(libcudart.so.11.0). When I run 'ipython'/'python' then import a package 'inplace_abn', it can import package successfully.

```
$ ipython
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 13:15:42) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import inplace_abn

In [2]:
```

But when I do the same operation in a tmux environment. It fails... I also try this in a new tmux environment. it fails too.

```
$ ipython
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 13:15:42) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import inplace_abn
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3d62d7049f11> in <module>()
----> 1 import inplace_abn

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/inplace_abn/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .abn import ABN, InPlaceABN, InPlaceABNSync
      2 from .group import active_group, set_active_group
      3 
      4 try:
      5     from ._version import version as __version__

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/inplace_abn/abn.py in <module>()
      6 import torch.nn.functional as functional
      7 
----> 8 from .functions import inplace_abn, inplace_abn_sync
      9 
     10 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/inplace_abn/functions.py in <module>()
      6 from torch.autograd.function import once_differentiable
      7 
----> 8 from . import _backend
      9 
     10 

ImportError: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

In [2]:
```

What is the principle of this phenomenon...? I am very confused. Hope someone can help me.

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

It is the reason of CUDA. This package (inplace_abn) is compiled with cuda extension. I add the path of CUDA explicitly in ~/.bashrc, then the problem gone.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda:$CUDA_HOME
```